# org babel sql results output in raw form

Tags: babel, postgresql

Is the way to get same output as in terminal with `ob-doc-sql`.

Executing the sql-query in org will process results into org-table
ignoring other than table information. It doesn't fare well with 
multiple query in the block as show below will squash both into 
single table.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :engine postgresql :database postgres
  SELECT 'hello';
  SELECT 'hello', 'world';
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| ?column? |          |
|----------+----------|
| hello    |          |
| ?column? | ?column? |
| hello    | world    |
```

header argument `:results` with **output** or **verbatim** value produce correct structure but table formatting is stripped out. But stil doesn't produce any terminal like output as shown below.

```
#+RESULTS:
: ?column?
: hello world
: ?column?  ?column?
: hello  world
```

Althouh expected output can be produced via shell execution,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output
  psql postgres -X -c "SELECT 'hello'" -c "SELECT 'hello', 'world';"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
 ?column? 
----------
 hello
(1 row)

 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
 hello    | world
(1 row)

#+end_example
```

Comment: Nice question! Does `ob-doc-sql` provide a `:session` header? Sometimes adding session will alter the results. Also did you try adding `:results verbatim` to the block?

Comment: according to https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-sql.html there is no session support.

adding `verbatim` has similar result as `output`

Answer (score 2):

ob-sql [passes](https://github.com/bzg/org-mode/blob/70d98b56b2c859f2299723ad5395e3af94bc88e5/lisp/ob-sql.el#L270) the `-A` or `--no-align` option to `psql` that

> Switches to unaligned output mode. (The default output mode is aligned.) This is equivalent to `\pset format unaligned`.

ob-sql's `:cmdline` line doesn't help, because it's passed to psql after all other parameters, and [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) does everything in order:

> When either `-c` or `-f` is specified, psql does not read commands from standard input; instead it terminates after processing all the `-c` and `-f` options **in sequence**.

Even if we add `:cmdline "-c '\\pset format aligned'"` it won't affect the result.

So to get the output you want apply `:results verbatim` and then call `\a` inside your code blocks:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :engine postgres :database postgres :results verbatim
\a
\pset footer 1
SELECT 'hello';
SELECT 'hello', 'world';
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
SET
 ?column?
----------
 hello
(1 row)

 ?column? | ?column?
----------+----------
 hello    | world
(1 row)

#+end_example
```

`\pset footer 1` brings `(1 row)` messages back, as ob-sql turns them off too with `-P footer=off`.

I think it should also be possible to copy the `org-babel-execute:sql` function to your config and change it however you like. I don't see an easier way to customize this behavior.